# DAX: Group AVG of only those who are in latest Quarter per FY

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I am struggling to get the AWF-Team measure corrected as below.
Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Q: Why is the 4 included from rowid 7? 'The latest cylce' you've mentioned, but that row isn't in the latest cyle, it's from 1/3, not from 4/2?

Comment: TJ - Employee level AVG of all his rows first (because he showed up in latest cycle) then Group AVG (for only those who are in latest cycle)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where you'd get the 3.75 from. According to this code it would pick up all the score from the "feedback team" where it's not null (including the 4 and 6 from above, hence:(3+4+4+6)/4 = 4.25. you should add a condition if you want only the last two rows. And why add a "4 " in the end?